# How to install NetApp SystemManager as a service under linux?

Tags: init.d, netapp

It seems the NetApp dropped the web interface support some time ago and now they require you to instal and run SystemManager, which happens to be a webserver running on localhost.

It seems that their installer does not include any init.d script and I am looking for one that would allow me to make it run as a true service.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `NetApp OnCommand System Manager` is more like a standalone app and was not meant to be run as service/init.d script, but if you still want it like that, try adding `java -jar SystemManager.jar` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I am working on this and soon I will have a solution. It seems that that's just an webapp, but it needs few configurations to make it work properly as a server. I cannot imagine any reason for NetApp to remove the webgui and making a client. More work, worse customer experience.